# Add integer days to date and then getDay(), getMonth(), GetFullYear()

Tags: javascript, date

Anyone can help me please in. I want get integers from slider bar and Add them into date and format the date like  'Friday 27th Mar 2015' all the time when I change slider it will change the Day and Date. I have this code but with slider it is not working. I want to modify this code,

```
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December");

 var day = new Array("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "18th", "19th", "20th"
                , "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st");

            var WeekDay = new Array("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "TuesDay", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday");

            var newdate = document.getElementById("slider").value = value;


            // 

            var d = new Date();

            d.setDate(d.getDate() + newdate);

            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = WeekDay[d.getDay()] + " " + day[d.getDay()] + " " + m_names[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
```

Comment: I know this is a little off-topic, but the format you're looking for wouldn't have the ordinal suffix: "Friday 27th Mar 2015" would simply be "Friday 27 Mar 2015". This format (with or without day of week) is recommended by some historians and genealogists.

Comment: thanks for your quick answers but It is not working IT is giving me different result If i assign var newdate = 1; then Result is = TuesDay 6th March 2015. I do not  understand this result.

Comment: @Muryali JavaScript days start on Sunday. Your array starts on saturday. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

The `setDate` method sets the day of the month. It does not "magically" overflow into the next month if, say, today is the 3rd of march and you add 70 days to the counter.

**However**

You can get a library called `moment`, which is extremely helpful to do this kind of stuff. The reason I am recommending this rather than reinventing the wheel is because it would take you a lot of work to take into account:

- Months with varying length
- Leap years
- ...

So. Get moment (using bower, npm or whatever it is you're using. Or just here: http://momentjs.com/ ). The last part of your code then becomes:

```
// Pre-setting values
var newdate = 173;

var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

var day = new Array("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "18th", "19th", "20th" , "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st");

var WeekDay = new Array("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "TuesDay", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday");


var d = moment(new Date());
d.add(newdate, 'days');

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = WeekDay[d.day()] + " " + day[d.date()] + " " + m_names[d.month()] + " " + d.year();
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/q8ms5us2/1/

Please note that moment also has a locale library, which is something you might want to look into to make your code easily adaptable, when it comes to other languages or datetime formats...